# Simplifying/Minifying an if else statement in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a short if/else statement in my flask app which I would like to make shorter (preferably 1-line) since it is to be used in every route in my application. Here is an example route for context (I am using a custom locale system instead of Babel because I couldn't figure out how to do exactly what I wanted with Babel):

```py
@main.route("/")
@main.route("/", subdomain="<lang>")
def home(lang = None):
    if lang:
        locale = Locale(lang)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("main.home", lang="en"))

    return render_template("home.html", l=locale.write)
```

The code in question is:

```py
if lang:
    locale = Locale(lang)
else:
    return redirect(url_for("main.home", lang="en"))
```

If anyone knows a way to shorten this code it would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this conditional expression one-liner:

```
def home(lang=None):
    return render_template("home.html", l=Locale(lang).write) if lang else redirect(url_for("main.home", lang="en"))
```